# JSON Schema: Combine multiple references in properties together to "AdditionalProperties = false"

Tags: arrays, json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I'd like to separate the properties according to their type, such as:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "properties": {
    "allOf": [
      { "$ref": "type/blue.json#/definition" },
      { "$ref": "type/red.json#/definition"   }
    ]
  }}
```

my problem is that when referencing it (#ref) it does not recognize any property and when adding the additionalProperties it gives me an error

in file blue.json and red.json I have two different fields defined, such as:

```
# blue.json
"definition": { 
    "name": {
       "type": "string"                
    }
  }

# red.json
    "definition": {
        "age": {
           "type": "string"
        }
      }
```

and the error it gives me is as if it did not recognize the "age" field and name field in red.json and blue.json file due to the "additionalProperties = false"

If you could help me please I would be very grateful

Answer (score 1):

This is what the "unevaluatedProperties" keyword is for -- it "sees into" subschemas that contain "properties" keywords (and additionalProperties, and patternProperties too), taking those subschemas into consideration when checking what properties haven't been defined and therefore aren't allowed.

Note that this keyword is new to draft2019-09, so if you're using a draft7 or earlier evaluator it is not available.